# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento, authentication, admin

I installed magento twice on my localhost. But each time it give me error shown in image with correct username and pass

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you just installed a fresh version? Which version? Have you got any custom modifications? Have you tried to debug this *at all*?? This problem may be relevant to the SUPEE-7405 patch and upgrading to Magento 1.9.2.3/1.14.2.3

Comment: I downloaded it today from github

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Try to raise the `max_input_vars` of your local server.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the login. I have running Magento 1.9.2.4 twice, one on public server and one in a Vagrant VM.

After download of all Data and Tables in the local Machine i was not able to login in the Backend.

**The Error Message "Invalid Form Key" have the symptom, that the Post-Var "form_key" or Session-Var is missing, then will in the Session.php generating a new form_key and the compare will failing.**

Do you have control to set the Variable "MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE" to TRUE (Apache Hostconfiguration), then can you looking in the Apache Error log for more details.

In my case was this a Problem to saving Sessions on the Disk (NFS-Share). I have changed the place into the VM, then was working the login.

The best Way is to change the *Session to "db" in "app/etc/local.xml"* and set the nesting Level of Post-Vars deeper.

TIP: use a VM with XDebug and set the XDebug Vars in the .htaccess (Apache) and a compatible Editor with XDebug. A good way to control/check your Magento Installation go with a script file from "magerun.net".

Comment: I've set session path to the one configured in php.ini: `<session_save_path><![CDATA[/var/lib/php5/sessions]]></session_save_path>`. It looks like there is a problem when default one is on VM shared folder.